# Unable to retrieve lat and long locations in mapView using swift ios

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview

```
let latitude = NSUserDefaults .standardUserDefaults().valueForKey(klat) as! Double

 let longitude = NSUserDefaults .standardUserDefaults().valueForKey(klong) as! Double


let location:CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude)

//Second Location lat and long
let latitudeSec:CLLocationDegrees = 11.0100
let longitudeSec:CLLocationDegrees = 77.3620

let locationSec:CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitudeSec, longitudeSec)

let span:MKCoordinateSpan = MKCoordinateSpanMake(1, 1)

let region:MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(location, span)

mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)


let myAn1 = MyAnnotation(title: "Office", coordinate: location,subtitle: "MyOffice");
```

I am unable to retrieve the map locations here which I have stored in the app earlier using NSUserDefaults in the keyword "klat and "klong" It shows the following error:

> "Could not cast value of type '__NSCFString' (0x1604da4) to 'NSNumber' (0x971800)"

Comment: Why should I store it here? I have done it in another class.

Comment: Looks like you are storing a String and trying to retrieve a Double

Comment: Can you show the part of the code where you setObject

Comment: btw NSUserDefaults has a method called setDouble(forKey:) to store it and doubleForKey() to retrieve it

Comment: self.lattitude=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%16f",currentLocation.coordinate.latitude];
    self.longitude=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%16f",currentLocation.coordinate.longitude];
   
   [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:self.lattitude forKey:klat];
   [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:self.longitude forKey:klong];

Comment: It is done using objective C

Comment: Anyway that's what I said you saved a string. Save the double `currentLocation.coordinate.latitude` using the method I said

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use following code for storing the latitude and longitude

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setDouble:latitude forKey:klat]
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setDouble:longitude forKey:klong]
```

And for retrieving

```
let latitude = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().doubleForKey(klat)
let latitude = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().doubleForKey(klong)
```